# Parsing string AngularJS $http to .NET Core controller

Tags: c#, angularjs, json

I'm trying out AngularJS in combination with NET Core. Currently trying to parse a "string username", "string password" and "bool rememberMe", but both strings are null no matter what I do. I've even tried parsing a constant value as seen below, the parameter "test", but even that doesn't work. I've confirmed in Fiddler that the script is in fact parsing the value, so the controller basically just can't "fetch it".

Below is my AngularJS loginController code.

```
var login = angular.module('login', []);
login.controller('LoginController',
    [
        '$scope', '$http', '$window', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
            $scope.submit = function () {
                var data = { test: ':D' };
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/admin',
                    data: data
                }).then(function success(response) {
                    alert(response.data.test);
                });
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Below is the code for my ActionResult meant to fetch the value being posted to it.

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(string test)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                test,
                bla = "BLA"
            });
            //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            //{
            //    if (UserSystem.Login(username, password, rememberMe, HttpContext))
            //    {
            //        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Accepted;
            //        return Json(new
            //        {
            //            returnUrl = "/admin/dashboard"
            //        });
            //    }
            //}
            //HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            //return Json(new
            //{
            //    error = "Username and/or password do not match"
            //});
        }
```

I've also tried specifying the Content-Type, but also without luck. Either way, in Fiddler the request always seems to per default be application/json.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: are you sure you are making the request to the correct end point ?
what does /admin route to ?

Comment: I'm sure. As you can see in the ActionResult, it returns a constant value "bla = "BLA" and I can get this value just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to request an object in the controller, rather than "string username", "string password" and "bool rememberMe".

The controller now looks like this:

```
    public class LoginModel
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index([FromBody]LoginModel model)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password))
        {
            if (UserSystem.Login(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, HttpContext))
            {
                HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Accepted;
                return Json(new
                {
                    returnUrl = "/admin/dashboard"
                });
            }
        }
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        return Json(new
        {
            error = "Username and/or password do not match"
        });
    }
```

And the AngularJS controller now looks like this:

```
var login = angular.module('login', []);
login.controller('LoginController',
    [
        '$scope', '$http', '$window', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
            $scope.submit = function () {
                var data = {
                    username: $scope.username,
                    password: $scope.password,
                    rememberMe: $scope.rememberMe
                };
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/admin',
                    data: data
                }).then(function success(response) {
                    $window.location.href = response.data.returnUrl;
                }, function fail(response) {
                    swal('Error!', response.data.error, 'error');
                });
            }
        }
    ]);
```